# How should I reattach laminate stair treads to eliminate movement and noise?

Tags: stairs

I apologize if the terminology is off for the components of a staircase. Please correct me in comments and I'll update the question.

My home has laminate stair treads that were fastened down with what looks like construction adhesive and 3 nails ~ 1" from the back in the stringer locations on top of what looks like an mdf/plywood (not sure what this piece of blank board is - false tread?) . They squeak like crazy and lift up in the front on several steps (presumably over the years the laminate treads have separated from this board.

( I have carpet squares on the steps right now, so the center stringer screws would not be visible but the outer 4 would be if I went with that approach )

I was going to pull them all up, scrape and re-apply sealant, and and hit them with 6 trim screws + countersink them and cover with a filler pen. Does that sound like an appropriate solution?

I was thinking of adding some type of cork/padding in between instead of the sealant but still use the trim screws. Is that a viable option?

/Cheers.

(Not my stairs/vid, but I think they look a lot like this situation but I don't have the moulding. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iOsbprpe5g&t=4m35s)

Comment: What's a "wood pen"? What's an "offset bit"? I think you're on the right track, but  I want to understand the details. I'd call the underparts "rough treads".

Comment: Also, you might consider using brass or bronze screws and leaving them flush (exposed). Might be a nice trim detail and filler may not hold up.

Comment: countersink*, wood filler* pen like what minwax offers.

Comment: @isherwood It's my understanding that if I didn't screw them down, using a padding is not the right approach 100%, but is that an option between the rough tread and the pretty top tread?

Comment: The problem with padding is that it will allow quite a bit of movement, which is problematic when you have something screwed down _loosely_. You'll be grinding away at the screw holes over time and knocking any filler out. I'd use construction adhesive and screws under your carpet. Solid is as quiet as padded. If no one else gets around to it I'll post an answer later.